# I typed g++ -o main.cpp main and I lost my program

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I've just written the following into the console:

```
g++ -o main.cpp main
```

and my `main.cpp` is gone.

Did I just lose my 3 hours of work?

Comment: Try `g++ --help` or `man g++`

Comment: In a word, "yes". What to learn from this - use a version control system such as git or mercurial, and commit to it every few statements you write.

Comment: Have you learned about cmd files? Perhaps your first cmd file might always make a backup copy.  Then when you see your cmd mistake ... someday, you will want to try make, which has a steeper learning curve.  Step 1 - type in an executable cmd file (perhaps build?), that runs the g++ command to compile helloWorld.cpp.  When it works without overwriting your input, proceed to step 2.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you did. The `-o` flag specifies the output file (`main.cpp` in your case since that's the file name immediately following it):

```
g++ -o main.cpp main
    \_________/ \__/
              \    \_This is the input file.
               \_____This specifies the output file.
```

In other words, you have told the compiler to try and compile what would normally be your executable, and write the results to your source file (overwriting it). A more suitable command would have been:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp
```

---

This is one of those *educating* moments that developers experience from time to time (including old hacks like me), the sort of thing that should convince you to do regular commits to `git` (or other source control system), or compile code with a build system rather than possibly complex command lines.

Comment: I do understand what is going on here - I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: Also why to not type commands by hand, but have them in a makefile or other build script.

Comment: @o11c: the more complex the command, the more likely you will get it wrong. Contrast `gcc -std=c11 -O2 -funsigned-bitfields -fallow-single-precision -fgimple -c -o prog.o prog.c` against `make` :-) Obviously, you still have to get it right the *first* time (when configuring the build system) but, once that's done, you don't generally need to worry about it again.